# Android : AsynkTask and HttpConnection errors

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i'm new in java and android programming , and by following some tutorial i've tried to make an Android App that have to make a Http request to a php page for reading the output string. I get the following errorr in doInBackground method :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Exception MalformedURLException is not compatible with throws clause in 
     AsyncTask<Void,String,String>.doInBackground(Void[])
    - Exception IOException is not compatible with throws clause in AsyncTask<Void,String,String>.doInBackground(Void[])
    - Exception IOException is not compatible with throws clause in AsyncTask<Void,String,String>.doInBackground(Void[])
    - implements android.os.AsyncTask<java.lang.Void,java.lang.String,java.lang.String>.doInBackground
    - Exception MalformedURLException is not compatible with throws clause in 
     AsyncTask<Void,String,String>.doInBackground(Void[])
```

Any idea ? 
Thank You

That's the MainActivity.java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    TextView finalResult;

public class ConnessioneAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>{

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Void... v) throws IOException, MalformedURLException{


            try{
            URL url = new URL("http://myUrl");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = read.readLine();
            String html = "";
            while (line != null){
                html += line;
                line = read.readLine();
            }
            return html;
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            catch(Exception ee){
                System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute(){
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result){
            finalResult.setText(result);
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asynkButton);
        finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                ConnessioneAsyncTask runner = new ConnessioneAsyncTask();
                runner.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: clearly it says your URL is not accurate

Comment: try the same url in your browser... see if your get anything.. My point is, your URL may be invalid

Comment: http://myUrl is only for example the true url is a valid website url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doInBackground` Method does not declare any `throws clause` and you are trying to add throws declaration. you need to handle all exception with in your code only instead of declaring it using throws clause. Here is javadoc for the [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)  method. So in a nutshell you need to remove throws clause in order to make it valid.